# I am trying to make an Application that connects to a WebService

Tags: android

I am trying to make an Application that connects to a WebService and I want to replace this code with an index.html file

This is my code:

```
    import java.util.Map;
    import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;

    public class AndroidWebServer extends NanoHTTPD {

        public AndroidWebServer(int port) {
            super(port);
        }

        public AndroidWebServer(String hostname, int port) {
            super(hostname, port);
        }

        @Override
        public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
            String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
            Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();
            if (parms.get("username") == null) {
                msg += "<form action='?' method='get'>\n  <p>Your name: <input type='text' name='username'></p>\n" + "</form>\n";
            } else {
                msg += "<p>Olá, " + parms.get("username") + "!</p>";
            }
            return newFixedLengthResponse( msg + "</body></html>\n" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is an English language site. Please post your question in that language.

Comment: You can't replace a dynamic web-page with a static one and keep the functionality...